# ansbile template weird formatting

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to create yaml based configuration files.   Everything is working except that the lines after a loop is being indented for some reason.

So when I have this...

```
- job_name: {{ inventory_hostname }}
    pipeline_stages:
        - regex:
            expression: {{ pipeline_regex }}
        - labels:
{% for labels in pipeline_vars %}
{{ labels }}:
{% endfor %}
        - timestamp:
            source: date
            format: 2006-01-01 15:00:00.000000
```

the timestamp field is improperly indented..

```
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: test
      pipeline_stages:
        - regex:
            expression: Test
        - labels:
            Test:
            Test2:
            - timestamp:
            source: date
            format: 2006-01-01 15:00:00.000000
        - drop:
```

If I put a comment in after the for loop that gets indented and the timestamp value is in the right place.   I tried to remove the whitespace in the loop and that didn't fix the problem.  I assume this is something simple but I am stumped.

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/.

Comment: Not sure what else you are looking for.   The code snippet I supplied SHOULD work but it DOESN'T work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason the file shouldn't be indented properly. The template

```yaml
shell> cat scrape_configs.yml.j2
- job_name: {{ inventory_hostname }}
    pipeline_stages:
        - regex:
            expression: {{ pipeline_regex }}
        - labels:
{% for labels in pipeline_vars %}
{{ labels }}:
{% endfor %}
        - timestamp:
            source: date
            format: 2006-01-01 15:00:00.000000
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    pipeline_regex: Test
    pipeline_vars:
      - '            Test'
      - '            Test2'
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: scrape_configs.yml.j2
        dest: scrape_configs.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat scrape_configs.yml
- job_name: test
    pipeline_stages:
        - regex:
            expression: Test
        - labels:
            Test:
            Test2:
        - timestamp:
            source: date
            format: 2006-01-01 15:00:00.000000
```

Comment: So I put my entire template on this test site.

https://j2live.ttl255.com/

And it works fine on that website.   Yet when I run it with ansible, it keeps adding additional whitespaces on that timestamp line.